# SBS2003 OWA not displaying images on external side

Tags: iis, exchange-2003, windows-sbs-2003, outlook-web-app

I've got an SBS 2003 server with companyweb/remote owa site. After authenticating remotely to the https:/servername/remote site, and then clicking on Use Outlook Web Access, the mail/owa site displays only limited amounts of data with Loading... displayed (see first image). This is different when viewing the site on the server itself (see second image). Different browsers will display different types of data (last screenshot is Chrome - first two are IE). I feel IIS permissions on the virtual directories is the cause, but not certain. Forms-based authentication etc is working ok etc. Any suggestions? Authentication and getting email via ActiveSync is not a problem. I don't want to break anything, and it's not a major problem because the users only get their email via outlook and iphones anyway without problems.  I'm more interested in finding out for my own info so please give me some suggestions to try. Thanks for looking!

[image: external view OWA on IE]

---

---

[image: Internal view localhost owa]

---

---

[image: External view OWA on Chrome]

Comment: I've had this issue, I believe one of the following fixed it http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/resetting-owa-folder-iis-security-permissions-exchange-2003.html http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/Fixing-Damaged-Incorrectly-Configured-OWA-2003-Installation.html

Answer (score 0):

We eventually ended up paying an ActiveSync specialist to have this resolved. It took about an hour and they completely re-installed .net, .asp, re-applied all permissions and physical and virtual directories. I wish I had taken a video of the procedure, but didn't. Good luck if you have this same problem!